# Pandas missing add row method (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

Is it just me, or is Pandas missing a dedicated method for adding a row? Especially now that append() has been depreciated.

The only ways I know of is to create a second df (even if it's just one row) and concat the two, or use the loc[-1] method which doesn't allow you to easily pick which columns to add data to. Am I missing something?

I created my own method which can add a full row or only specified columns. I'm just surprised that they have an insert method for columns but not rows.

Comment: nah you're not missing anything, this seems to be the case. you would mind sharing your own method though?

Comment: It wouldn't let me paste it here as it was too long. But basically the method takes a list of values and an optional list of columns. If no columns list of provided you have to have the same elements as columns in the existing df in the same order. If a columns list is provided then the values are added for just those columns

Comment: I mean also share you method with your question, if it's not too much trouble

Comment: I'll post it to gitHub later this weekend. And send over the link 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right.

Since `Append` method is deprecated you should `concat` to add row.

But you have the possibility to design a custom adding function as follows.
I think this is a wise thing to do :

**a simple method :**

```py
import pandas as pd

def add_row(df, row_data):
    new_row = pd.DataFrame(row_data, columns=df.columns)
    return pd.concat([df, new_row], ignore_index=True)

# Example usage
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})

# Data for the new row
new_row_data = {'A': [7], 'B': [8]}

# Add the new row to the DataFrame
df = add_row(df, new_row_data)
```

```
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
3  7  8
```

**Implement a row-checking process :**

We could want to check for instance if :

- row is a `list` or a `dict`
- check row columns content versus original dataframe columns if it's a `dict`
- row length if it's a `list`

Concatenation is processed if checking test is ok otherwise the function returns a message error.

```py
import pandas as pd

def add_row(df, row_data):
    """Custom method for adding a row to a dataframe"""
    if isinstance(row_data, dict):
        # Check if row data is a dictionary
        if set(row_data.keys()) != set(df.columns):
            raise ValueError("Row data doesn't match DataFrame columns")
        new_row = pd.DataFrame(row_data, columns=df.columns)
    elif isinstance(row_data, list):
        # Check if row data is a list
        if len(row_data) != len(df.columns):
            raise ValueError("Row data doesn't match DataFrame columns")
        new_row = pd.DataFrame([row_data], columns=df.columns)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Row data format not supported")
    
    return pd.concat([df, new_row], ignore_index=True)

# Example usage
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})

# Data for the new row
new_row_data = {'A': [7], 'B': [8]}

# Add the new row to the DataFrame
df = add_row(df, new_row_data)
```

```
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
3  7  8
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this is very similar (yours is better) to what I did.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct! Not only Pandas, but also all the softwares are not perfect, even stupid sometimes. There is no build-in function in Pandas to add a DataFrame row like to use insert function to add a column.

As far as I know, there are 3 methods to add a row in Pandas DataFrame. Like you mentioned: append(), loc[-1] and concat. But if you want to add a row to a specific index, you need to separate the original DataFrame into 2 DataFrames like df1 and df2, then concat([df1, row, df2]).

Comment: I don't even care about inserting at a specific location. It just seems weird to not have a dedicated insert function. .loc[] is for locating/filtering. Concat is for combining dfs - neither seem purpose built for adding rows (though obviously both can be). I'd even be happy with a SQL approach where you have to put the input statement inside a string or docstring. Seems like an oversight on a very popular library not to have it.

Comment: I agree with you. But it is true that Pandas really doesn't have the function. If I am the creator of Pandas, I must add the function into Pandas. But I am not. I know loc or concat are not dedicated to do this. But I don't see there is a better way. Like I mentioned, not only Pandas, but also all the softwares are not perfect, even stupid sometimes.